# How to launch synergy in i3

Tags: i3

I have two PC.Both of them is Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa and I replace cinnamon with [i3](https://i3wm.org/) which is a tilling window manager.

Recently,I want to share keyboard and mouse with [synergy](http://synergy-project.org/)

But I can't launch synergy in i3,everything is Ok if I switch to cinnamon.
anybody know how to solve it?THX

Comment: If I launch synergy in d-menu,the error output as:`System tray is unavailable, quitting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I don't know why,but comment the i3 config can fix it.

```
{
         status_command i3status
 #        tray_output primary
}
```

then restart i3 and synergy, enjoy synergy now.

Answer (score 2):

The likely issue is that i3 has not launched its system tray because a primary display is not evident.  This might be considered a bug, but here are two options to allow the tray to start:

1. **Preferred:** Define the primary output.  You can do so using xrandr (replacing `eDP1` with the name of your display).  A list of output names can be obtained by running `xrandr` without any arguments.  This command may be run externally, but probably needs to run after each restart so if included in the i3 config use the exec prefix.

   `exec xrandr --output eDP1 --primary`
2. Use an alternate `tray_output` other than "primary".  Output names can be used as the i3 tray output.

   `tray_output eDP1`

After making either of these changes to the i3 config you will need to restart i3.  `restart` is bound to `$mod+Shift+r` by default.